# Get the path to a directory in an AWS .NET 6 Lambda deployed via GitHub Actions

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, github-actions, aws-cdk

I'm deploying an AWS .NET 6 Lambda via GitHub Actions. The function handler needs to read a bunch of text files. The folder structure looks like this:

```
text-files
  file1.txt
  file2.txt
  ...
Program.cs (handler is here)
MyFunction.csproj
```

I'm trying to get the path to `text-files`, but this is failing:

```
var directoryPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "text-files");
// var directoryPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "text-files");
// var directoryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"), "text-files");
```

When I print out the value for `directoryPath`, all approaches above return:

```
/var/task/text-files
```

This fails because the above path does not exist. What's the right way to get the path to `text-files` so I can read each file in that folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment.contentrootpath) to get the root path of your application and then construct your path from there.

Comment: Is this to be used for ASP.NET apps only? The Lambda I'm deploying is a console app. To be more precise, I created it via `dotnet new lambda.EmptyFunction` as mentioned on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-cli.html.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, have you ensured that you're actually publishing those files with the app to the Lambda runtime?

Comment: Wow. I thought `dotnet lambda package -o publish.zip -c Release` would take care of everything, but now that I've looked at the zip file, I don't see the text files there. Is there another command to make sure the files are included in the zip?

Comment: Change the files and/or directory item(s) in your `.csproj` file(s) to have `CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"`. That should ensure that your files are included in the published output.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.